# How to print only pattern, not a line?

Tags: search, ex-mode

I've got the following shell command:

```
$ ex +'/>\zs\w\+\ze</p' -scq! /dev/stdin <<<$"foo>bar<buzz"
foo>bar<buzz
```

however it's matching the whole line, instead of the pattern.

How can I print only the matching pattern (`bar`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

`ex +'s/.*>\(\w\+\)<.*/\1/|p' -scq! /dev/stdin <<<$"foo>bar<buzz"`